# Why same notebook allocating large different vram in two different environment?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, gpu, tensorflow2.0

you can see this notebook is trainable in kaggle using kaggle’s 16gb vram limit : https://www.kaggle.com/firefliesqn/g2net-gpu-newbie

i just tried to run this same notebook locally on rtx3090 gpu where i have torch 1.8 installed and same notebook allocating around 23.3 gb vram,why is this happening and how can i optimize my local environment like kaggle? even if i reduce batch size compared to what is used in kaggle,still locally my notebook allocates around 23gb vram

in kggle i see torch 1.7,tensorflow 2.4 installed and locally as i use rtx3090 so new version of torch and tf is recommended,hence i used torch 1.8.1 and tensorflow 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, TensorFlow allocates max available memory detected.

When using TensorFlow, one can limit the memory used by the following snippet:

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  # Restrict TensorFlow to only allocate 12GB of memory on the first GPU
  try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(gpus[0],
        [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=12288)],
```

where `12228 = 1024x12`

Another solution (see discussion below) is to use (works for OP) (use this only if you do not have a specific upper limit of memory to be used) :

```
 tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/set_memory_growth

In PyTorch, this is even easier:

```
import torch

# use 1/2 memory of the GPU 0 (should allocate very similar amount like TF)
torch.cuda.set_per_process_memory_fraction(0.5, 0)

#Can then check with
total_memory_available = torch.cuda.get_device_properties(0).total_memory
```

Comment: please check cell 11's  max_memory_allocated(): function from here : https://www.kaggle.com/firefliesqn/g2net-gpu-newbie

i am using this function in both kaggle and in local gpu where i have rtx3090 connected..if you check this notebook : https://www.kaggle.com/hidehisaarai1213/g2net-read-from-tfrecord-train-with-pytorch

this is similar like the past notebook link that i shared but this notebook didn't allocate all gpu vram in tensorflow 2.4 iirc
is it okay that tf allocating all memory?

Comment: TensorFlow does that by default (full allocation), while it uses only a part of it during the training that is another thing so to say; the only way to limit GPU memory usage in TF by code (I personally am aware of) is the one described above.

Comment: in that notebook i am reading/processing tfrec data using tf and training using torch models.so which memory allocation limit code i should use from your above two examples? pytorch one or tf one?

Comment: I would say both: to either limit the memory from TensorFlow to 0 and use PyTorch 1/2 from memory, or a small constant from TensorFlow (1GB/2GB max), the latter just to make sure TF does not break (though the operations performed for reading I expect to be done on CPU). Because TF by default when it sees GPU available will allocate max memory available, leaving PyTorch with no memory to train you models.

Comment: say for batch size 16 my training notebook need 16 gb vram,in pytorch automatically it allocated 16gb,,,for tf can i do that? i am disliking this idea of tf allocating whole memory :(
like pytorch i want to force it to use as much memory as my notebook need to train my configured model,how can i do that? iirc in past tf versions i didn't face this whole memory allocation issue

Comment: Yes, you use the code I provided above for tensorflow if you want to prevent it from allocating the total memory.

Comment: And then PyTorch will use max(total - tf_allowed) depending on what is needed.

Comment: you are hardcoding it to allocate 12gb vram but sometimes i might will need more memory

Comment: Then only allocate on TensorFlow side.

Comment: so i am using this code : 

import tensorflow as tf
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)


why you didn't recommend me to use this instead? this is not allocating extra vram for me,is it not recommended?

Comment: This didn't actually work before & for me in certain situations. I am happy it works for you, I am updating the answer so that it includes your observation.

Comment: In addition, this could work if TensorFlow does not exceed a specific (memory) threshold in your case. If you don't want it to exceed a threshold, then set_memory_growth(True) is not a good solution.